# What's the difference between "sólo", "únicamente" and "solamente"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, uso-de-palabras

According to the [RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=s%C3%B3lo):

> solo o sólo.
>
> 1. adv. m. Únicamente, solamente.

In what situations is preferred to use one over the other?

Are they interchangeable?

> Sólo es una pregunta simple.
>
> Solamente es una pregunta simple.
>
> Únicamente es una pregunta simple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are synonyms (as RAE says in the definition you give) so in my opinion they are interchangeable. They are all **adverbs of manner** and they all mean that there is only one way of doing it, it's just in one thing or that you want it without anything else. So these sentences would mean exactly the same to me.

- in just one way

> **Sólo**/ **Solo** hay una forma de hacerlo.
>
> **Solamente** hay una forma de hacerlo.
>
> **Únicamente** hay una forma de hacerlo.

- it's just in one thing

> El canguro vive **sólo**/ **solo** en Australia.
>
> El canguro vive **solamente** en Australia.
>
> El canguro vive **únicamente** en Australia.

- without anything else.

> **Sólo**/ **Solo** quiero un café.
>
> **Solamente** quiero un café.
>
> **Únicamente** quiero un café.

As **solo** is shorter it will be probably more used than the others in oral speech but any option is ok.

Just take care that **solo** (when it doesn't have the accent mark) can also be other things apart from an adverb of manner, so **it wouldn't be interchangeable in the other cases**. For example it wouldn't be possible in these sentences:

> Está **solo** en casa.
>
> Quiero un café **solo** (sin leche).

Comment: Just to note that "solo", without the accent mark, is a synonym of "alone". "Estás solo en casa?" means "Are you alone at home?"

Comment: @JuanZe Not always (it can mean other things), but many times they are synonyms :)